# the volume of a cut of a paraboloid.

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to calculate the volume of a cut of a paraboloid.
i.e. I need to find the volume of the set $V\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ where $$V=\{(x,y,z)| a\leq z\leq 1,\quad x^2+y^2\leq z\}.$$

It's easy to calculate using this method:
$$\iiint_V 1=\int_a^1\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt z}r dr d\theta dz=\int_a^1 \pi zdz=\pi z^2/2|^1_a=\pi/2-\pi a^2/2.$$

But I have this question: is there a straight forward explanation (without calculating) to see that the volume of $V$ is equal to the volume of$$V_1=\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2≤1-a,\quad x^2+y^2≤z≤1\} \quad?$$

Comment: Basically, the inequalities used to describe $V$ are equivalent to that in $V_1$. The lower and upper limits of $z$ are $a$ and $1$ respectively, so the base circle of the solid has the equation $x^2+y^2=a$ and the top cover circle has the equation $x^2+y^2= 1$, hence we have the inequality, $a\leq x^2+y^2\leq 1\Rightarrow 0\leq x^2+y^2\leq 1-a$, which denotes the plane circular region in between. But this inequality could also necessarily denote region bounded by a cylindrical surface, and so to avoid the confusion the restriction, given by the other inequality is just for paraboloid surface.